# Best way to replace cursor in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

I want to replace the cursor code from my stored procedure

```
DECLARE CursorXD CURSOR FOR
   SELECT 
       IDOrdre, Quantity,fabnum
   FROM prod_ordreplanificationdetail
   WHERE fab = @num
     AND ordre = @ord

OPEN CursorXD 

FETCH NEXT FROM CursorXD INTO @correctionnumsap, @correctionquantite, @correctionnumfabrication

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   EXEC INSERT#prod @idordre = @correctionnumsap,
                    @quantite = @correctionquantiteneg,
                    @fabnum = @correctionnumfabrication

   FETCH NEXT FROM CursorXD INTO @correctionnumsap, @correctionquantite, @correctionnumfabrication
END

CLOSE CursorXD 
DEALLOCATE CursorXD
```

What is the best way to replace this cursor to increase the performance??

Any suggestion?

Comment: You will need to re-write the stored procedure being called in the cursor to operate against the entire set of data that is being iterated on by the cursor, instead of operating on one row at a time.  Anything else would still be row-by-row, which would be no more efficient that the cursor used here...

Comment: If you post the definition of the stored procedure, we can offer suggestions on how this might be done...

Comment: Need more **Description** for the `exec INSERT#prod`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a option, but I made a couple of assumptions

```
INSERT INTO prod
SELECT IDOrdre, Quantity,fabnum
FROM prod_ordreplanificationdetail
WHERE fab=@num
  AND ordre=@ord
```

Assumptions:

1. SP INSERT#prod only does an `INSERT` and no other data manipulation
2. SP INSERT#prod inserts into a table called `prod` and there are only three columns in the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use WHILE loop instead of CURSOR by maintaining the nth row value. It is too good performance wise compare to CURSOR. If you tell clearly what you need, so we can walk into same road.